# How to print elements (xpath) text on a different line in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xpath

The title may sound confusing but I'm trying to get the `.text()` from an Xpath all on separate readable lines. For example you don't see a book that is written in one line.
I've tried using for loops and had the idea of splitting the text so every 10 words it will add a new line but I can't seem to get it to work. However I am very new to python and I'm pretty sure using for loops works and `.split()` works but I just can't figure it out.

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[1]')
text = text.split()

for i in text:
    something
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: this title is very confusing I just realised so I'm going to repost this question with a new title.

Comment: No edit the question and change the title

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of words:

```py
try:
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[1]').text
    list_of_words = text.split() # split by spaces between words
    sentence = []
    for word in list_of_words:  
        sentence.append(word)
        if(len(sentence) == 10):
            print(" ".join(sentence))
            sentence.clear()
    print(" ".join(sentence))
except:
    print("Text is not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.

```
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/p[1]').text
para1 = text.split(" ")
length = len(para1)
for i in range(0,length,10):
    line = " ".join(para1[i:i+10])
    print(line)
```